# Wind moving through my hair?

Tags: word-choice, creative-writing

What's a creative way to say 'Wind was moving through my hair?'
A breeze was drifting through my hair?

Comment: The wind tousled my hair.

Comment: A breeze drifted into one ear and out the other...my hair got in the way.

Comment: A zephyr ruffled my purple prose.

Comment: _A breeze teased my satiny mop into a dramatic coif._  _A gale occasioned a little tornado on my head._

Answer (score 2):

Think of what the wind was doing in or near your hair. What was your hair doing as a result of the wind? Then in your description of that you will have opportunities to be creative.

A wind generally blows rather than moves.

Comment: That´s very good advise, thank you Elliot :)